# MIMIC-III medication order frequencies

Tags: mimic-iii

So is it true that there is no information of the frequency of medications ordered in MIMIC? The prescriptions table just has the dosage of each administration and the days the prescription was "active", but no indication of the frequency (e.g. daily, bid, q8 hr, prn, etc). I understand that there's the option of looking for the item id in inputevents and trying to deduce the frequency from that, but it won't tell you if the doses were ordered separately or scheduled (two one-time orders or one twice-daily order).

Is this true? If so why was the frequency part of the Rx lost from the prescriptions database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the frequency of medications was erroneously omitted in the update of MIMIC-II to MIMIC-III. We plan to incorporate this in an update to MIMIC-III.